# codeigniter session expire automatically

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

i m using codeigniter web application framework.A session expire problem occured.when using ajax in codeigniter , then codeigniter's session expire automatically..how to fix this problem..please give me response asap.

Answer (score 0):

Create a MY_Session.php library in application/libraries with the following code, that extends CI_Session.

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session {
   /*
    * Do not update an existing session on ajax calls
    *
    * @access    public
    * @return    void
    */
    public function sess_update()
    {
        if ( ! (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') )
        {
            parent::sess_update();
        }
    }
}
```

This extension will make sure session is only updated if the call is not an ajax call.